# FB login - Unable to generate 28-character key hash unique to my development environment using password "android"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm integrating Facebook login in my android app.
I have followed the steps from the fb-login/quickstart/ from the following link
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
In step 4 -  Add Your Development and Release Key Hashes, a key hash is to be generated.
ie a 28-character key hash unique to the development environment which is to be generated.
For that I have run this command in the terminal with the required information.
The following is the command I have executed.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\xxxxx\.android\debug.keystore" | "E:\Projects\xxx\Fb-login\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "E:\Projects\xxx\Fb-login\bin\openssl" base64
```

when I run this command everything works fine and asks me for the password.
when I enter "android" as the password the generated string is "mYH+" instead of a 28-character key hash.
Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());

            Log.i("Base64", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("Name not found", e.getMessage(), e);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Run this code on your device and use the Base64 log value from logcat

Ps: Your production build hash will be different!

Comment: I want to generate the hash key through command line, not by code @Dhruv

Comment: Do you need to hash key to register it at Facebook App panel?